# Javascript function does not show the div after clicking on a href without JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, function

I've been working on a small website for school and i want to add a button that'll make a 'login' div pop up out of thin air, i've already written the HTML/CSS for it but i haven't got too much experience in Javascript, that's why i am hoping for a possible answer here, i'm writing an open() function to open the div, and if it gets activated again it should close.

```js
var open = false;


function open() {
 open == false ? document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'block' : document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'none';
 open = !open;
 console.log(open);
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 min-width: 1px;
 min-height: 1px;
 }

html,body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 115%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
 }



header {
 margin-top: 2%;
 background-color: #FF0000;
 margin-left: 12.1%;
 width: 75%;
 height: 180px;
}

header p {
 font-size: 64px;
 margin-left: 40%;
 padding-top: 4.5%;
}

#nav {
 margin-left: 12.1%;
 width: 75%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #FF0000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

#nav ul li a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 11px 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 }
 
#content {
 margin-left: 12.1%;
 width: 75%;
 height: 73.9%;
 background-color: #FF0000;
}

footer {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #FF9900;
 width: 75%;
 margin-left: 12.1%;
}

#nav #right {
 float: right;
}

#nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 
}

#nav ul li {
 float: left;
}

#nav ul a:hover {
 transition: 0.5s;
 background-color: #FFFF0F;
}

#login {
 display: none;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 width: 25%;
 height: 20%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#login form {
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-top: 8%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
  <script src="js/LoginMenu.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <header><p> Lost Story </p></header>
 <div id="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
    <div id="right">
     <li><a href="#" onclick="open()">Log in/register</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  <div id="login">
   <form>
    <p> username: </p>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <p> password </p>
    <input type="password" name="pass">
   </form>
  </div>
 
 
 </div>
 <footer> Website made by a rock </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm still looking for an answer, last time no one tried to answer my question about javascript i hope this time it'll work out.

Thanks!

Comment: At the time you're retrieving `open`, it's a function. Actually you should rename both, the variable and the function, since you're shadowing the native global `open` method.

Comment: This `open == false ? document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'block' : document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'none';` is bad! Do not use it as an if/else. If you are going to use it, do it the right way.  `document.getElementById('login').style.display = open == false ?  'block' : 'none';`

Comment: @Teemu Even after doing this it has the same result.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the tip, and yeah i noticed that just now, it however does not solve my problem

Comment: @LucasOuwens Apparently you've made something wrong then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `open()` points to `window.open()` on the global scope.

So rename your function to `loginOpen()`

Also your HTML is not valid. An `UL` can only have `LI` and `OL` as children. You have a `DIV`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: Thanks for helping me! This works greatly, also the div is there to set it to the right, we aren't allowed to use inline css for these things

Answer (score 0):

actually you don't necessarily need javascript to work with dialogs.
I did a JSFiddle for you : https://jsfiddle.net/69fjnnx9/

You can see that with the `:target` CSS pseudo-class you can play on the `display` property of your login div, along with setting your link in the menu to `#login`, i.e the div you want to target.

Then, I added a 'Close' button in your login div which points to '#' and makes the login div disappear by loosing target when clicked.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="open()">Log in/register</a>
```

Calls

```
window.open()
```

instead of the expected open() function you had created.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open and try to avoid property names already used by the global Window object.